# Image resizing relative to image center

Tags: c#, image, resize

I am currently working on a project based on Kinect and I can't find a way how to resize the image relative to the image center. I managed to update image width and height as I move my hands and I get the picture resized, but relative to the TopLeft corner. So, basically if you imagine a rectangle, the top left corner is always fixed, while other corners move. The picture resizes only in the directions from right to left and from bottom to top.

I first tried to use ScaleTransform to resize the image and there i could specify the transform origin ( which I was setting in the middle of the picture), but it does not allow to update the image size in the result... so it makes no use to me..

So, if anyone could give my some sort of an idea of how to approach the task of resizing in all directions dynamically I would be very grateful. Maybe there is some way how to set the point to a different value than top left?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to first translate the image to the origin, apply your scaling and then translate it back to the original center. See the scaleImage() function in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792835/image-manipulation-wont-display-transformed-image).

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I also just thought I could update margins to shift the image in the directions i need while scaling, thus making an impression that the scaling occurs from center.

Comment: If you have a way to move the origin to the center of your image, that would work. Otherwise, translating to the origin and back doesn't involve that much overhead in terms of coding or computation (the transformation matrices are multiplied together before applying them to the points in your image).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RenderTransformOrigin` to move the center point of a scale action.  For example:

```
<Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5, 0.5" />
```

I had a similar question related to resizing on a DP from the center of a `UserControl`.  The discovery of how to resize from the center of the object is mentioned in one of the comments of the accepted answer.

[Growing UserControl Size with Style Trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568214/growing-usercontrol-size-with-style-trigger)

Comment: I think I saw that before, but the problem with ScaleTransform is that it doesn't update the scaled Width and Height of the picture.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding the need.  If you are wanting to take a picture and shrink or grow it `ScaleTransform` should do that, and `RenderTransformOrigin` will allow you to move the origin of that scale.